# Where is the vTaskGetRunTimeStats output printed out?

Tags: freertos

In FreeRTOS vTaskGetRunTimeStats, pcWriteBuffer is getting populated with the time, but where is it printed out? I mean which part of the tasks.c prints out the contents of pcWriteBuffer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vTaskGetRunTimeStats()` populates `pcWriteBuffer` with ascii string containing the run stats.  It's up to you to print that string.  You can simply do that with:

```
printf("%s", pcWriteBuffer);
```

For more info, see [vTaskGetRunTimeStats docs](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#vTaskGetRunTimeStats).

Comment: Thank you! I missed that part